# BigCommerce PHP hello world app intsall error

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a BigCommerce app using this [code](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/). But when I try to run the code locally I am getting this error.

**Console Error**:

```
GET http://localhost/customer/current.jwt?app_client_id=***** 404 (Not Found)
```

When I install this app on the BigCommerce store I am getting a blank page in my apps. Can't understand why this is happening. Please help me solve it.

Here is my code for `.env`

```
BC_AUTH_SERVICE=https://login.bigcommerce.com
BC_CLIENT_ID=****************** 
BC_CLIENT_SECRET=********************
BC_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost/bigCommercedemo/auth/callback
```

Due to this error, I can't install my app. Please help